# Bootstrap Typeahead working on only two clicks in my scenario and Need to make work on dynamically for 20 rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

Here are code examples of my actual scenario. I need to call typeahead only when clicking once on the show button. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6egfvwo/2)
Down below is my **HTML** table.

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>City 1:</td>
        <td>
            <input id="city1"></input>
            <button id="myButton1">Show</button>
            <button id="clear1">Clear</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City 2:</td>
        <td>
            <input id="city2"></input>
            <button id="myButton2">Show</button>
            <button id="clear2">Clear</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I am using bootstrap-typehead these are as follows what's within the `<head>`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/3.1.0/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
```

Then there is my **jQuery** function, utilised to display a list of cities when the 'show' button is clicked and when 'clear' is clicked: destroy the previously initialised typeahead. This works only when I double click the show button. I got to make this work in with a singular button click.

```
$('#myButton1').click(function() {
    $('#city1').trigger('keyup');
    $('#city1').focus();
    $('#city1').typeahead({
        source : [ 'Alabama', 'Alaska','Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming' ],
        autoSelect : false,
        items : 1000,
        minLength : 0
    });
});

$('#clear1').click(function() {
    $('#city1').val('');
    $('#city1').typeahead('destroy');
});
//trigger the typeahead
$('#myButton2').click(function() {
    $('#city2').trigger('keyup');
        $('#city2').focus();
        $('#city2').typeahead({
        source : [ 'Alabama', 'Alaska','Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming' ],
        autoSelect : false,
        items : 1000,
        minLength : 0
    });
});
$('#clear2').click(function() {
    $('#city2').val('');
    $('#city2').typeahead('destroy');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix needing to double-click the Show button, move the `.trigger()` and `.focus()` after `.typeahead()`

i.e.

```
$('#city1').typeahead({...});
$('#city1').trigger('keyup');
$('#city1').focus();
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5o8srLkm/

---

For code that works with any number of rows I suggest adding CSS classes to the html. This aids finding the associated input field of the clicked button using jQuery's [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).

(I also destroy `.typeahead()` before creating it - in case it already exists for the input field)

```js
$('.btnShow').click(
  function() {

    var $cityInput = $(this).prevAll('.cityInput'); // find the input associated with this button

    $cityInput
      .typeahead('destroy')
      .typeahead({
        source: ['Alabama', 'Alaska',
          'Arizona', 'Arkansas',
          'California', 'Colorado',
          'Connecticut', 'Delaware',
          'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
          'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana',
          'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
          'Louisiana', 'Maine',
          'Maryland', 'Massachusetts',
          'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
          'Mississippi', 'Missouri',
          'Montana', 'Nebraska',
          'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
          'New Jersey', 'New Mexico',
          'New York', 'North Carolina',
          'North Dakota', 'Ohio',
          'Oklahoma', 'Oregon',
          'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
          'South Carolina',
          'South Dakota', 'Tennessee',
          'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
          'Virginia', 'Washington',
          'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin',
          'Wyoming'
        ],
        autoSelect: false,
        items: 1000,
        minLength: 0

      });

    $cityInput
      .trigger('keyup')
      .focus();
  });

$('.btnClear').click(function() {

  var $cityInput = $(this).prevAll('.cityInput'); // find the input associated with this button

  $cityInput
    .val('')
    .typeahead('destroy');
});
```

```html
...
    <tr>
      <td>City 1:</td>
      <td>
        <input id="city1" class="cityInput" />
        <button class="btnShow">Show</button>
        <button class="btnClear">Clear</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>City 2:</td>
      <td>
        <input id="city2" class="cityInput" />
        <button class="btnShow">Show</button>
        <button class="btnClear">Clear</button></td>
    </tr>
...
```

*Note `<input />` doesn't need a closing tag*

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p90nv67g/

Answer (score 2):

You are triggering the keyup before initializing the typeahead and hence it is not showing for the first time. Initialise before and then trigger it and you are done.

```
 function() {

                    $('#city1').focus();
                    $('#city1')
                            .typeahead(
                                    {
                                        source : [ 'Alabama', 'Alaska',
                                                'Arizona', 'Arkansas',
                                                'California', 'Colorado',
                                                'Connecticut', 'Delaware',
                                                'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
                                                'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana',
                                                'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
                                                'Louisiana', 'Maine',
                                                'Maryland', 'Massachusetts',
                                                'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
                                                'Mississippi', 'Missouri',
                                                'Montana', 'Nebraska',
                                                'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
                                                'New Jersey', 'New Mexico',
                                                'New York', 'North Carolina',
                                                'North Dakota', 'Ohio',
                                                'Oklahoma', 'Oregon',
                                                'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
                                                'South Carolina',
                                                'South Dakota', 'Tennessee',
                                                'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
                                                'Virginia', 'Washington',
                                                'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin',
                                                'Wyoming' ],
                                        autoSelect : false,
                                        items : 1000,
                                        minLength : 0
                                        });
 $('#city1').trigger('keyup');
}
```

Comment: problem is i will be calling webservice while click on show. For each letter it should not trigger. Only after stops writing and click on show it should call webservice and provide list of suggestions. then user needs to typeahead to select the required one

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML Datalist instead. Check the code below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#search").on("input", function(e) {
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val === "") return;
  //You could use this to limit results
    var countries= ['Alabama', 'Alaska',
                                                'Arizona', 'Arkansas',
                                                'California', 'Colorado',
                                                'Connecticut', 'Delaware',
                                                'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
                                                'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana',
                                                'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
                                                'Louisiana', 'Maine',
                                                'Maryland', 'Massachusetts',
                                                'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
                                                'Mississippi', 'Missouri',
                                                'Montana', 'Nebraska',
                                                'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
                                                'New Jersey', 'New Mexico',
                                                'New York', 'North Carolina',
                                                'North Dakota', 'Ohio',
                                                'Oklahoma', 'Oregon',
                                                'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
                                                'South Carolina',
                                                'South Dakota', 'Tennessee',
                                                'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
                                                'Virginia', 'Washington',
                                                'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin',
                                                'Wyoming'];
   var dataList = $("#searchresults");
   dataList.empty();
    for(var i=0, len=countries.length; i<len; i++) {
     var opt = $("<option></option>").attr("value", countries[i]);
     dataList.append(opt);
    }
 });
})
</script> 
</head>

<body>

<p>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td>City 1:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Type Something" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>City 2:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Type Something" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off"></td>
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td>City 3:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Type Something" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off"></td>
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td>City 4:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Type Something" list="searchresults" autocomplete="off"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
 <datalist id="searchresults"></datalist>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: problem is i will be calling webservice while click on show. For each letter it should not trigger. Only after stops writing and click on show it should call webservice and provide list of suggestions. then user needs to typeahead to select the required one

Answer (score 2):

You have to trigger click event to typehead script to call show list in the input field using `.trigger()` event.

An answer for your second question is below to call typehead only once when clicks on show button,  Please check https://jsfiddle.net/manishjethva/thmr9k2L/8/ for more detail.

```
$('body').data("btn1",true);
$('#myButton1').click(
                function() {
            var btn1 = $('body').data("btn1");
                    if(btn1 === false){
            alert('typeahead calls only once, clear to call again.');
            return;
          }
                    $('#city1')
                            .typeahead(
                                    {
                                        source : [ 'Alabama', 'Alaska',
                                                'Arizona', 'Arkansas',
                                                'California', 'Colorado',
                                                'Connecticut', 'Delaware',
                                                'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
                                                'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana',
                                                'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
                                                'Louisiana', 'Maine',
                                                'Maryland', 'Massachusetts',
                                                'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
                                                'Mississippi', 'Missouri',
                                                'Montana', 'Nebraska',
                                                'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
                                                'New Jersey', 'New Mexico',
                                                'New York', 'North Carolina',
                                                'North Dakota', 'Ohio',
                                                'Oklahoma', 'Oregon',
                                                'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
                                                'South Carolina',
                                                'South Dakota', 'Tennessee',
                                                'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
                                                'Virginia', 'Washington',
                                                'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin',
                                                'Wyoming' ],
                                        autoSelect : false,
                                        items : 1000,
                                        minLength : 0

                                    });
             $('#city1').trigger('keyup');  
             $('#city1').focus();   
             $('body').data("btn1",false);
                });

        $('#clear1').click(function() {
            $('#city1').val('');
            $('#city1').typeahead('destroy');
      $('body').data("btn1",true);

        });
```

Comment: not able to select from the dropdown. Dropdown disappears immediately.

Comment: @Karthik, I have updated my answer by putting $('#city1').focus(); event after trigger event, Please check latest jsfiddle URL jsfiddle.net/manishjethva/thmr9k2L/8. I hope the latest answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

as [K Scandrett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544886/k-scandrett) mentioned 
To fix needing to double-click the Show button, move the .trigger() and .focus() after .typeahead()

i.e.

```
$('#city1').typeahead({...});
$('#city1').trigger('keyup');
$('#city1').focus();
```

**Second Part**

only works with show button, we will disable it while the user is changing input

```
$("#city1").on("input propertychange",function(){
$('#city1').typeahead('destroy');
    });
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6egfvwo/48/)